# Form Submit on new page has another new form in php

Tags: php, forms, validation, error-handling, registration

I have two registration page at one I have collected user data and another one i have matched otp

page one

```
<form name="frm" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="nam">
 <input type="email" name="email">
 <input type="submit" name="sub">
</form>
```

page 2

```
<form name="frm" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="email2" value="<?php echo @$_POST['email'];  ?>" disabled>
     <input type="text" name="otp">
     <input type="submit" name="sub">
    </form>
```

these two pages are registration page and I want to send data to the database but it returns an error on submit second page form all $_POST[] variables automatic empty...

Comment: try <?php echo $_POST['email'];  ?> without "@"?

Comment: using `disabled` on an element will prevent that from being posted - that said your question is a little unclear

Answer (score 0):

An disable input no send the value in form, you can insert the email in hidden input, the correct form is:

```
<form name="frm" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo @$_POST['email'];  ?>" disabled>
    //put the value email on hidden input.
    <input type="hidden" name="email2" value="<?php echo @$_POST['email'];  ?>">
    <input type="text" name="otp"  value="<?php echo @$_POST['nam'];  ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="sub"  value="<?php echo @$_POST['sub'];  ?>">
</form>
```